# How can I create a ValueNode without an ObjectNode?

Tags: jackson-databind

For some reasons, I need to set a property with an instance of `ValueNode` class or an instance of a subclass of `ValueNode` class.

```
class SomeMessage {

    private JsonNode someValue; // unknown/lazy
}
```

How can I create an instance of `ValueNode` without an `ObjectNode`?

Currently I only can do this.

```
setSomeValue(
    OBJECT_MAPPER
       .createObjectNode() // no other way than this?
       .set("id", 1.0d)
       .get("id")
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer.

With given instance of [`ObjectMapper`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html), you can get an instance of [`JsonNodeFactory`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/JsonNodeFactory.html) using [`getNodeFactory()`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#getNodeFactory--).

And the you can create `ValueNode`. e.g. [`numberNode`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/JsonNodeFactory.html#numberNode-java.math.BigDecimal-).